# Embedding a region of code in a help file

Tags: c#, sandcastle

I am using sandcastle to build my help file.

Is there a way to add code samples from actual C# files?
Ideally, I would have C# files with region, reference the region from sandcastle. Sandcastle would then embed the content of the region when building.
Is this feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [<example>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w4cf933.aspx) tag.

Here's a reference of tags you can use:  [Recommended Tags for Documentation Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Interesting but not what I want.

Comment: I am looking for a way to reference C# code from AML, not a way to embed samples from C#.